# Materializecss menu works fine only on one page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, materialize

I'm using `materialize-sass` gem in my Rails app and have some troubles with using it. It works fine only in root (home) page, and in some others but not on full site.

The `.button-collapse` losts functionality and menu doesn't work. I just click on it, or tap (in mobile device) and nothing happens. Sometimes it works after page refresh, sometimes don't. Always after clicking on `.button-collapse` to the url adds `#!` in the end (it's logically understandable), except the root (home) page.
I think it might be the jQuery problem, but I initialize collapse button in `assets/javascripts/application.js`, as:

```
$(function() {
  $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
});
```

like in official guide. Also I'm trying to use `document.ready`. All my related code located in `application.html.erb` and looks like this:

```
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="col s12 nav-wrapper">
          <%= link_to 'Blog', root_path, class: 'brand-logo' %>
          <a href="#!" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
          <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li>
                <%= "Hello, #{current_user.username}" %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li>
                <%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %>
              </li>
              <% end %>
          </ul>
          <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
            <% if user_signed_in? %>
              <li>
                <%= "Hello, #{current_user.username}" %>
              </li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to 'Sign out', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
              </li>
            <% else %>
              <li>
                <%= link_to 'Sign in', new_user_session_path %>
              </li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
```

Comment: Are there JS errors in the browser console by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

As I use turbolinks in my Rails project I needed a way to deal with them. Just adding [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem and this code: `//= require jquery.turbolinks` in JavaScript manifest file solve the problem.
Also there is much **easy** way to solve this by adding this:

```
$(document).on('ready page:change', function() {
  Waves.displayEffect(); // Initialize buttons wave effects
 $(".button-collapse").sideNav(); // Initialize collapse button
});
```